# Are there any segulos or tefillos that one can say before a big test?

Tags: segulah

I am wondering if there are any special segulos or tefillos that one can say if he wants to have success - this example, a big test. The segulah/tefillah could be related to knowledge, but a segulah for success in general works too, i.e., if someone were to daven for success in an upcoming interview.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you have to do your worldly effort, and that God is in control. Sorry, no magical potions or trinkets here.

I would think [Psalm 90](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.90?lang=bi) is a fitting one to say; it reminds us of how small we are, asks for "a heart of wisdom", and concludes with a request for our efforts to prosper.